# Submitting and printing LaTeX PDFs

Tags: pdf

I have used LaTeX to write many supplemental essays for my college applications. My father, who just learned of this, says that I need to call the colleges to whom I sent PDFs generated with LaTeX and make sure that the documents I sent are visible to them (the PDFs don't have boxes representing characters that the compute doesn't recognize) and that when printed, the printer does not replace any LaTeX symbols or ligatures with whitespace.

I said that because the documents are PDFs, it doesn't matter what's on the PDF because PDFs can be read on computers with Adobe Acrobat (which all universities' computers should have). He said that didn't matter and I should call the colleges. Note that in the Common App (which is used to submit applications), it lets me preview what I am submitting and the LaTeX PDFs appeared intact there.

Is he right? I think it would be horribly embarrassing to call admissions offices and ask if my PDFs are visible to them.

---

**Details about the document**

- Standard Computer Modern font
- Only new command is a command that puts vertical whitespace before and indents a new paragraph
- Packages used: `amsmath` and `hyphenat`
- TeXShop used to create the PDF

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a MWE as the documents are on my computer at home and I'm on vacation.

---

This may not be exactly the right site on the SE network for this, so I apologize if this is off-topic. If so, please refer me to the correct site. PDFs Thank you.

Comment: Check whether all fonts are embedded in the PDFs you sent. Either use `pdffonts` (a command line tool) or look for the `Properties` of the PDF in your PDF viewer which should include information about the fonts. It should list all fonts as 'Embedded' (subsets are fine). It is still possible that some characters may not *print* correctly as this depends on the print driver. However, this is not peculiar to LaTeX-generated PDF or to PDF as opposed to other formats. It is unlikely that the PDF you sent were images unless you did something special to ensure this.

Comment: @cfr I added some more details about the document. Does that help?

Comment: Not really. It is likely that the fonts are embedded if you are using a recent MacTeX installation and, say, pdfTeX as engine and haven't changed the defaults. But I would personally never count on this. I would always check the PDF to ensure that the fonts are correctly embedded. And, as I say, that is not a guarantee. With a poor enough print driver, the printed output may be crap. However, it is unlikely that they are using anything quite that poor, assuming they print the document out at all. Note that the fact that you used LaTeX as opposed to something else is no real reason to worry.

Comment: (Although use of **microtype** can cause issues as can use of **pdfpages** and various other odd things, but these do not generally cause issues on laser printers or inkjets. The odd character might not print, but nothing terrible. I've only had significant problems using print drivers in photocopiers.)

Comment: @cfr I didn't use `microtype`, so that shouldn't be a problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Most college applications that allow you to upload PDFs have a preview window for the documents you uploaded, with the understanding that they would see PDFs on the screen exactly as in the previewer. Since I haven't been an admissions counselor, I can't confirm that for certain, though. (Also, as noted above, the printer may make a difference, along with whether they print directly from Chrome or open it in a PDF viewer.)

Comment: It certainly can happen that a pdf is faulty and/or can't be viewed correctly on some/all pdf viewers or fail to print. But this is rare and it can happen with all sort of pdf creation methods (last time I saw a broken pdf it was created by word and then sent by mail and suddenly it had all sort of black boxes). I wouldn't worry about it. I'm also rather certain that a college would notify you if a file is obviously broken.